# Why do I keep getting this error when trying to create a virtual environment with Python 3 on MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, virtualenv, python-3.6, python-venv

So I'm following a book that's teaching me how to make a Learning Log using Python and the Django web framework. I was asked to go to a terminal and create a directory called "learning_log" and change the working directory to "learning_log" (did that with no problems). However, when I try to create the virtual environment, I get an error (seen at the bottom of this post). Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this to move forward in the book?

I already tried installing a virtualenv with pip and pip3 (as the book prescribed). I was then instructed to enter the command:

learning_log$ virtualenv ll_env

And I get:

bash: virtualenv: command not found

Since I'm using Python3.6, I tried:

learning_log$ virtualenv ll_env --python=python3

And I still get:

bash: virtualenv: command not found

`Brandons-MacBook-Pro:learning_log brandondusch$ python -m venv ll_env
Error: Command '['/Users/brandondusch/learning_log/ll_env/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '-
-default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: if you `cd` into the `learning_log` dir, try `./virtualenv ll_env` (notice the dot-slash prefix)

Comment: I'm getting the same bash:

`bash: ./virtualenv: No such file or directory`

Comment: can you confirm it's installed correctly? try `virtualenv --version` from terminal

Comment: Hmmm. This is interesting. This is what I get when I run `virtualenv --version`:

`bash: virtualenv: command not found`

When I try `pip install --user virtualenv`, I get: 

`Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/brandondusch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (16.4.
3)`

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu:**

The simple is if `virtualenv --version` returns something like `virtualenv: command not found` and `which virtualenv` prints nothing on the console, then virtualenv is not installed on your system. Please try to install using `pip3 install virtualenv`  or `sudo apt-get install virtualenv` but this one might install a bit older one.

**EDIT**

**For Mac:**

For Mac, you need to install that using `sudo pip install virtualenv` after you have installed Python3 on your Mac.

Comment: This is what I get when I try `pip3 install virtualenv` I get: 

`Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/brandondusch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (16.4.
3)`

When I try `sudo apt-get install virtualenv`, I am prompted for my computer's password and I get this: 

`sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: @BrandonDusch I thought you said you were installing on MacOS? My understanding is that MacOS does not have a package manager called `apt-get`

Comment: @BrandonDusch I have edited the answer please try that, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I am using MacOS. When I tried `sudo pip install virtualenv`, I got this:
`The directory '/Users/brandondusch/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

Comment: So I found that if I try `sudo -H pip install virtualenv`, that works. I successfully installed virtualenv version 16.4.3. 

However, when I then try to run the line `virtualenv ll_env`, I get a SameFileError. Should I delete one of the files?

Comment: you should not use sudo, as it is the root user, since when you use the dir normally it throws permission error.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought that’s what you suggested? sudo pip install virtualenv is what you edited into your initial response.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I restarted my computer and tried it again, but the error was still there. Then I tried `python3 -m venv ll_env` and it moved forward.